# What are the Legacy rewards for each leader?

Tags: state-of-decay-2

What are the current rewards for completing a playthrough with each leader?
How does each Legacy affect a new community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/state-of-decay-2-legacy-boon-guide/), legacies are next:

- **Amenities** (Builder legacy) - silent source of water and power for whole base
- **Charity** (Sheriff legacy) - daily packages of high-quality loot
- **Mobilization** (Warlord legacy) - receive pack of weapons, ammo and explosives in your first base
- **Favors** (Trader legacy) - 4000 influence and friendly trader visit (not sure if it is on regular basis)

Comment: On the trader legacy: The friendly trader visits your first base, and then sets up a friendly enclave that will give no quests, but will always have loads of resources to trade.